# How do you send single data when the button is pressed and not looping on the inside and stop the action when the button is release

Tags: android, navigation, ros, gamecontroller

So i am developing a controller in my mobile app using java and currently whenever i touch the button it will send 3 data in a row. when it should only be sending one data and another data when the button is release

i am able to set get the data when the button is release but not accurate since a lot of data was delivered

```
    upbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0.6;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    return false;
                }
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            return false;
        }
    });

    downbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_MOVE) {
                    nav_ctrl.linear.x = -0.6;
                    nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    leftbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 1.2;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;

                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                leftbtn.performClick();
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    rightbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = -1.2;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

I expect the to send only one line of data, example: "angular":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linear":{"x":-0.6,"y":0.0,"z":0.0}},

the output is similar but multiple data's was delivered

Comment: Actual output would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are publishing, regardless of the type of event.
You publish at least once when the `touch` starts, at least once when the `touch` ends and again for movement. Haven't checked, but it may also just keep firing if you hold the button.

Move `Publish` into the `ACTION_DOWN` block

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl); <--- This
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 1.2;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl); <--- Goes here

                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                leftbtn.performClick();
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Also, if it is an actuall button, there is an OnClick event that you can use

Comment: i was able to do this and deliver single data every pressed and released button.but i have one more problem when i press another button it will call the previous button that i pressed for about 2-3 seconds before it calls its own value.

Comment: @yenbico If this solved your problem, you can click the checkmark next to the answer. Regarding your other problem, I do not know what the problem is without seeing more code. My guess is that you need to call Publish AFTER changing nav_ctrl. I will change my answer

Comment: @yenbico Also, your ACTION_UP handling is different for every button...

Comment: @yenbico Updating your code breaks this question (so other users can't learn from it). Please ask another question if you have one!